# How do I find a circle from a center point and a point defining a normal through the center?

Tags: linear-algebra, 3d

I have a 3d center of a circle ($c$), another point ($p$) that defines a normal vector through the center, and a radius. I'm trying to find the parametric equation of the circle. I found this equation:

$$P = R\cos(\alpha)\vec u + R\sin(\alpha)\vec n \times \vec u + c $$

$\vec n$ is a unit vector perpendicular to the plane so I believe that is the unit vector in the direction $p - c$.

$\vec u$ is a unit vector from the center of the circle to a point on the circumference. I know there is an infinite number of values for $\vec u$ but my problem is that I don't know how to come up with one of them. Or even if this is the most appropriate equation to use in this circumstance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For any nonzero vector $(x,y,z)$, at least two of $(0,z,-y)$, $(-z,0,x)$ and $(y,-x,0)$ are also nonzero. (These are the cross products with the standard basis vectors.) Pick one and normalize.

Comment: Do all three of those vectors lie on the plane defined by the point $c$ and the normal vector $\vec n$?

Comment: @SSteve They are all orthogonal to $(a,b,c)$, as you can check for yourself by computing the dot products. In your formula $\vec u$ and $\vec n\times\vec u$ define a plane through the origin that’s parallel to your circle, and then you translate it to contain the circle’s center $c$.

Comment: Thanks. That did the trick.

Answer (score 1):

If you know $\vec n$ and you know $c$ then you know the equation of the plane of the circle.  Any unit vector in that plane will do.   Think about the plane.  You can parameterize the unit circle in the $xy$ plane by $\cos \theta \vec i + \sin \theta \vec j$ but you don't have to use $\vec i, \vec j.$  Any two orthogonal unit vectors will do.  You just start out at a different point on the circle when $\theta = 0.$  Same thing in your problem.

Comment: Ok, I can find the equation of the plane [from this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/752284/356678). But my knowledge of linear algebra is negligible so I don't know how to find a vector on that plane. So far all my searches show me how to get a normal vector to a plane, not a vector on the plane.

Comment: If you have a normal vector, any nonzero vector perpendicular to it will lie in the plane.  Just pick two coordinates, and solve for the third, using that $\vec x \cdot \vec n = 0.$  Now you can get a a unit vector $\vec u=\frac{\vec x}{||x||}.$

Answer (score 0):

The equation you found is correct.

That is, assuming what you really want is to find the parametrization of a circle on the path of intersection of the sphere's surface, and the plane containing $\vec u$, in relation to the normal vector.

Like saulpatz mentioned before me, all the equation is doing, is parametrizing a circle $\cos\theta \cdot \vec n + \sin\theta \cdot \vec m$ where $\vec n, \vec m$ are orthogonal unit vectors defining a plane in which the circle is laying in.

**Edit**:
I assume you are familiar with the parametrization of a circle of radius $R$ in the $xy$-plane, that is $\vec r(\theta) = [R\cos{\theta}, R\sin{\theta}]$.

This is simply the parametrization $R\cos{\theta} \cdot \vec i + R\sin{\theta} \cdot \vec j$, where $\vec i, \vec j$ are the canonical unit vectors given by $[1, 0, 0]$ and $[0, 1, 0]$ respectively. These two vectors can be thought of as [laying in a plane](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/7915/plane-determined-by-2-vectors/7918#7918), which in this particular case is just the $xy$-plane.

I am sorry I cannot provide you with any more insight, but try to convince yourself why it is the case that you can generalize this notion of parametrizing a circle $\vec s(\theta) = R\cos\theta \cdot \vec n + R \sin\theta \cdot \vec m$ where $\vec n, \vec m$ are orthogonal unit vectors laying in the plane spanned by $\vec n, \vec m$.

Comment: I'm having trouble interpreting "$\cos\theta \cdot \vec v + \sin\theta \cdot \vec m$ where $\vec m, \vec n$ are orthogonal unit vectors". How do $\vec v$ and $\vec n$ relate to one another?

Comment: My response was too long to include in a comment so I edited my original answer. Let me know if anything is unclear.

Comment: Was the $\vec v$ in the first equation supposed to be $\vec n$?

Comment: Yes, thanks for catching that. I will edit my answer.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification and your patience. I can definitely visualize that $\vec s(\theta) = R\cos\theta \cdot \vec n + R \sin\theta \cdot \vec m$ describes a circle on the plane. But I don't know the math for getting from my original points $c$ and $p$ to the vectors $\vec n$ and $\vec m$.

Comment: You define $\vec u$ as the unit vector positioned at the center of sphere ($c$) pointing towards any point on the circumference of the circle you want to parametrize. Note that $\vec u$ is not enough to define the plane your circle lies in, as there are an infinite amount of planes containing the vector $\vec u$.

Your normal vector $\vec n$, in a way gives a sense of what is considered *up* in your graph. Note also that $\vec u$ and $\vec n$ are generally not orthogonal, which is precicely why you use $\vec n \times \vec u$ for $\vec m$ in the equation defined above.